# Liferay - application too wide for column

Tags: liferay

The calendar widget is too wide for its column in a liferay site im making. I could fix this with some CSS but its a bit of a pain as you can select different time spans, etc. Im new to liferay so is there a standard way of dealing with width problems for applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what version you are using, use the Dock or Dock Bar to select a different Layout Template so that the column you're placing the large application is wider.

By default it is a two column 30/70 (meaning 30% for the first column, and 70% for the second).

Comment: I actually need the columns to be the width I currently have them at. If there's no default way of narrowing applications I guess Ill have to do a manual CSS overide. Thanks

Comment: @jd6699, I see you want to shrink the application. Sorry I miss read your question. Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to shrink the app. You can however, if CSS is not enough, use a [Liferay JSP Hook](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/portal+hook+plugins#section-Portal+Hook+Plugins-JSPs) to change the HTML\Code of the application in question to get it the way you would like.